How to dynamically tick or untick checkbox based on return boolean value from a function in Angular
I am trying to select or unselect checkbox based on a return value from a function in Angular. The function doesn't get called inside the cellrenderer.
I have a function
isChecked:boolean=false

isFunDone()
{if data.value == good.value)
return this.isChecked = true;
}
else{
this.isChecked =false;
}

and in columndef cellrenderer I am calling this:
cellrenderer: (params: { isChecked: any;}) => {
 
return `<input type ="checkbox" [checked]="this.isFunDone.isChecked =='true'"/>`


I think you are using aggrid, could you replicate the issue on one of their website examples and share the code in the question.

Yes @NarenMurali : using the aggrid

prefer storing the variable isChecked at each of the rows level, since checkbox is an individual row action

@NarenMurali : could u pls help me withth ecodebase

@DhanyaRaj. You need'nt use checked, just the value of your data will be true or false and the table show the checkbox checked or not according the value of the element. Remember that in angular we have variables in .ts, Angular binding the value of the variables in the .html.

If your function is a global one, do this.
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.isChecked = this.data.value === this.good.value;
}

// ...

cellrenderer: (params: ICellRendererParams) => {
    if(this.isChecked) {
        return `<input type="checkbox" checked>`
    } else {
        return `<input type="checkbox">`
    }
}

Please note that [checked] won't work inside the cellRenderer unless it's another component.

Old Answer:
This is the ag-grid way to do that
cellrenderer: (params: ICellRendererParams) => {
   const isChecked = isFunDone(params.value) ? ' checked': ''; //string
   return `<input type="checkbox"${ isChecked }`;
}

// external function accepting any as I dont know your datatype
isFunDone(data: any) {
 return (data === good.value);
}


Hi @codeandcloud , I need to check the checkbox , when it returns true value , write now even the condition is true ,getting back it as "" .could u pls help it

const isChecked = isFunDone(params.value) ? ' checked': ''; //string .I am tryign to get the boolean value here.liek in the isFunDone() - if teh condition satisfies Im trying to retutn boolean true

could you edit the question and give a little more context? I am a bit confused with your  isFunDone function. Does it accepts an input parameter?

It doesnt accepts any parameter, if the condition inside teh function satisfies , then return true , else false , and then if it is true then the checkbox should be ticked or else unticked ,(edited the question accordingly)

could you please help me with that  as I am stuck in this for past 4 to 5 days

data.value and good.value has no relavance to the data in the row? your post title specifies dynamically

thanks a lot for the old answer, that is what i needed .

i need one more help : currently i am doing like this :  const checked = params.data.A === params.data.B? 'checked' : '' , but in this case if two A and B values are null also , the checkbox is getting ticked , any help like if it is null then should not ge tiked

try  const checked = ( params.data.A && params.data.B && params.data.A === params.data.B) ? 'checked' : '' ;

I was able to get the output for the changes , but when I am trying to do the jenkins build , getting an error like TS2502 : 'ReadableByteStreamController' is referenced directly or indirectly in its own type   I havent made any change in that partivular file , please help here

Please post that as another question

Try using the following code to check or uncheck a checkbox based on the return value from a function. If you change the value to a "good" or "data" array, the checkbox will be unchecked in your output.
Html file:
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="isChecked" class="restricted-checkbox">

Css file:
.restricted-checkbox {
  pointer-events: none; 
}

Ts file:
export class MyComponent {

  data = { value: 'goodValue' }; 
  good = { value: 'goodValue' };
  isChecked = false; 

  // Method to check if values match and update isChecked
  isFunDone(): boolean {
    this.isChecked = this.data.value === this.good.value;
    return this.isChecked;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.isFunDone(); 
  }
}

